# Call an event method inside another event method

Tags: java, events, methods

In many cases it happened to me that I have written an event and later I discovered that in another event I am repeating same code again and again. For example I have this code in mouuseclick:

```
Text_1.addMouseListener(new org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseListener() {
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
            if(Highlighted)
                //UnHighlightWords();
            SetActualWord();
            selectedWord=ActualWord;
            fetchWord(ActualWord);

            DisplayData.label_translation.setText(String.valueOf(ActualWord.getSurahNumber()));

            ShowWord(ActualWord);

        }
```

and again I will have keypress event like this:

```
Text_1.addKeyListener(new org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyListener(){

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                             // ******recall Mousedown event*******
            }
        }
```

Is it possible to recall Mousedown method inside Keypressed to do not repeat same code again here or not? If yes how?

Comment: Are you trying to call keyPressed or repeat inside keyPressed?

Comment: Actually I want to call mousedown event in Keypressed event. Because the codes inside them are the same.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put all this code (which you already call it in mouse event) in a separate method and call the method whenever you need

```
        if(Highlighted)
            //UnHighlightWords();
        SetActualWord();
        selectedWord=ActualWord;
        fetchWord(ActualWord);


        DisplayData.label_translation.setText(String.valueOf(ActualWord.getSurahNumber()));

        ShowWord(ActualWord);
```

Comment: :) Thanks bro. I just asked this question to not copy the code and shrink the size of my codes.

Comment: @Moohebat Then make a standalone method that's called from both points.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. First get a reference to the object(which is an instance of an anonymous class by:

```
//I'll import the class for readability
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyListener;
//snip

//Do this line ***OUTSIDE*** the method, and in the class body!
MouseListener ml=new MouseListener(){
    void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        //Do something
    }
    //All the other methods as well
}
KeyListener kl=new KeyListener(){

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            ml.mouseClicked(new MouseEvent(Component source, ...)); //edit this part as needed
        }
}
Text_1.addKeyListener(kl);
```

You can now repeat the use of `kl` as needed. You can also manually invoke said listener by doing `kl.keyPressed(KeyEvent e);`

Comment: The problem is the comment line there. I want to not repeat code inside mousedown and instead call mousedown again. Informally, I want press the key but mouseclick event run in keypressed event.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a *KeyListener's* method inside a *MouseListener*'s method, as they are different events and used for different purposes, so you can't cast `KeyListener` event to `MouseListener`, and vice versa.

But you can call call `keyPressed()` inside  `keyReleased()` for example, as they are the same *event*.

---

**UPDATE**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class EventDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener,KeyListener{

 private JTextField text;
 private JButton saveButton,cancelButton;
 public EventDemo(){
  JPanel p = new JPanel();
  text = new JTextField("Event Demonstration");
  saveButton = new JButton("SAVE");
  cancelButton = new JButton("CANCEL");
  saveButton.addActionListener(this);
  cancelButton.addActionListener(this);

  text.addKeyListener(this);
  p.add(saveButton);
  p.add(cancelButton);
  p.add(text);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
  getContentPane().add(p,BorderLayout.CENTER);
  setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  setVisible(true);

  pack();
 }


 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
  Object source = ev.getSource();
  if(source== saveButton){
    System.out.println("Save button action");
}
  else if(source == cancelButton){
    //do something
    System.out.println("cancel button action");
}
 }

 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
     //see here we called keyEvent method
     keyEvents(e);
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

   }
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

   }

 /*
 this method created for key events
 */
 public void keyEvents(KeyEvent e){
  System.out.println(e.getKeyChar());
 }

 public static void main(String...args){
     new EventDemo();
 }
}
```

Comment: Aha. So if the events were the same kind how we could call them inside each other?

Comment: For instance two clickbutton events. How we can call one event inside the other one?

Comment: That's not for the Buttons, as buttons have one event `ActionListener`, for the other ones, see my edit I will add the some codes.